# How to extend styles in react component?

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a task when I need to extend the styles of a certain element. I take the basic styles through the module, and the additional ones will need to be done inside the function that will be in the component.
How can I extend the styles inside the component if I have already added styles from the module there?

```
import style from './styles.module.css';

const optionalStyles = {
  margin: "30px"
}


<p className={`${style.subtitle} ${optionalStyles}`}>42</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<p style={optionalStyles} className={`${style.subtitle}`}>42</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can:

- Create another class inside  your `styles.module` (or any other module) and add it conditionally:

```js
import style from './styles.module.css';

<p className={`${style.subtitle} ${someCondition ? style.otherStyles : ''}`}>42</p>
```

- Use inline styles:

```js
import style from './styles.module.css';

const optionalStyles = {
  margin: "30px"
}

<p className={style.subtitle} style={someCondition ? optionalStyles : {}}>42</p>
```